# Differents kind of classes inherit from an abstract class in android java

Tags: java, android, oop

I have two classes (ClassA and ClassB) that should be ListFragment. These two classes share behavior,thus I created an abstract class(AbstractClass). So AbstractClass inherit from ListFragment. So far I have my ClassA and ClassB that inherit from my AbstractClass which inherit from ListFragment.
The problem comes when I need another ClassC that should be a Fragment(not ListFragment) but also it need the behavior from the AbstractClass, but I cant inherit from it because ClassC should be just Fragment and my abstractClass is ListFragment.
I would like to have my ClassA,ClassB and ClassC inherit from my AbstractClass but being ClassA,ClassB Listfragment and ClassC just Fragment.
Im sure should be some design pattern in Java or good practice to solve this.

I know that java does not allow multiple inheritance.

Many thanks

Comment: all the three classes extends AbstractClass that extends ListFragment, but the ClassC will return the respective layout in onCreateView()

Comment: I dont know what you want to mean, but doing that I have to use in my ClassC layout a ListView, and I dont want to use a listview in that Fragment. I can put it invisible and dont use it but I think that is not very clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you extract common functionality to some helper class? Use composition instead of inheritance

Comment: Im not sure if I can use that because I need to use the lifecycle methods from the Fragments class.

Comment: You can call your helper methods from lifecycle methods

Comment: Yes you are right, I think I could do that,although I wouldnt like to have to do that. I would prefer have an abstract parent class for all the subclasses, I think is much cleaner..

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseAbstractFragment class which will be abstract and inherited from Fragment. Now create another ListViewAbstractClass(subclass of BaseAbstractFragment) and add ListView in it instead of inheriting it from ListFragment. Now subclass ClassA and ClassB from ListViewAbstractClass and ClassC from BaseAbstractFragment.

Comment: Interesting answer, but adding a single listview to the ListViewAbstractClass I wont have all the built-in help methods from ListFragment... I was looking for an answer similar to this, but I think this wont work..

Comment: What is the purpose of your abstract class? If it only have abstract functions then you can go with Interfaces as well.

Comment: No, I cant use interfaces. Actually I only have three abstract methods. Almost all functionality are in the lifecycle methods. The purpouse is manage in app billing methods, some of them in background and also dealing with the downloads after purchases.